# Remove Duplicate Time Zones From SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help removing duplicate time zone records from my select query without deleting them. The current result is as follows:

```
Employee ID #   Presence    Presence Start Time      Presence End Time     GMT Presence Start Time
691            Out Of Office    2020-02-01 04:30:00  2020-02-01 14:30:00    2020-02-01 12:30:00
691            Out Of Office    2020-02-01 05:30:00  2020-02-01 15:30:00    2020-02-01 12:30:00
691            Out Of Office    2020-02-01 07:30:00  2020-02-01 17:30:00    2020-02-01 12:30:00
691            Out Of Office    2020-02-01 13:30:00  2020-02-01 23:30:00    2020-02-01 12:30:00
691            Out Of Office    2020-02-01 20:30:00  2020-02-02 06:30:00    2020-02-01 12:30:00
435            Out Of Office    2020-02-01 00:15:00  2020-02-01 09:00:00    2020-01-31 16:15:00
5681           Out Of Office    2020-02-02 07:00:00  2020-02-02 15:45:00    2020-02-02 15:00:00
5681           Out Of Office    2020-02-02 08:00:00  2020-02-02 16:45:00    2020-02-02 15:00:00
5681           Out Of Office    2020-02-02 10:00:00  2020-02-02 18:45:00    2020-02-02 15:00:00
5681           Out Of Office    2020-02-02 16:00:00  2020-02-03 00:45:00    2020-02-02 15:00:00
5681           Out Of Office    2020-02-02 23:00:00  2020-02-03 07:45:00    2020-02-02 15:00:00
1927           Out Of Office    2020-02-02 07:00:00  2020-02-02 18:15:00    2020-02-02 15:00:00
1927           Out Of Office    2020-02-02 08:00:00  2020-02-02 19:15:00    2020-02-02 15:00:00
1927           Out Of Office    2020-02-02 10:00:00  2020-02-02 21:15:00    2020-02-02 15:00:00
1927           Out Of Office    2020-02-02 16:00:00  2020-02-03 03:15:00    2020-02-02 15:00:00
1927           Out Of Office    2020-02-02 23:00:00  2020-02-03 10:15:00    2020-02-02 15:00:00
```

The table returns duplicate GMT start times for the same employee, the database appears to be duplicating the results based on different time zones.

**I just want to remove the duplicate GMT Presence Start Times**

Employee ID # 691 should have 1 row, same with 5681 and 1927. Can someone please help?

Comment: Which one do you want to return?

Comment: so for `691` which row you want to retain ? Can you also show us your existing query ?

Comment: But you have different values for presence start time and presence end time. How would you like to deal with those? To me you should only store the GMT times and convert it to the concrete time zone where you want to display (or use) the out of office times.

Comment: Sorry, here is the query

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT
       [Employee ID #]
      ,[Presence]
      ,[Presence Start Time]
      ,[Presence End Time]
      ,[GMT Presence Start]

FROM  t1

I would like to keep Pacific Standard Time results for the Presence Start & End Times while removing the duplicate GMT rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `GROUP BY` clause to give unique values of `GMT Presence Start Time` for each employees `Presence` in the log. You need to use an aggregation function on the `Presence Start Time` and `Presence End Time` functions; I've chosen `MIN` in my example, but you might want something else.

```
SELECT [Employee ID #],
       [Presence],
       MIN([Presence Start Time]),
       MIN([Presence Start Time]),
       [GMT Presence Start Time]
FROM data
GROUP BY [Employee ID #], [Presence], [GMT Presence Start Time]
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Employee ID #   Presence        Presence Start Time     Presence Start Time     GMT Presence Start Time
435             Out Of Office   2020-02-01 00:15:00     2020-02-01 09:00:00     2020-01-31 16:15:00
691             Out Of Office   2020-02-01 04:30:00     2020-02-01 14:30:00     2020-02-01 12:30:00
1927            Out Of Office   2020-02-02 07:00:00     2020-02-02 18:15:00     2020-02-02 15:00:00
5681            Out Of Office   2020-02-02 07:00:00     2020-02-02 15:45:00     2020-02-02 15:00:00
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8efc4/1)

Alternatively you can use window functions on the `Presence` Start and End times:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Employee ID #],
       [Presence],
       FIRST_VALUE([Presence Start Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Employee ID #], [Presence], [GMT Presence Start Time] ORDER BY [Presence Start Time]) AS [Presence Start Time],
       FIRST_VALUE([Presence End Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Employee ID #], [Presence], [GMT Presence Start Time] ORDER BY [Presence End Time]) AS [Presence End Time],
       [GMT Presence Start Time]
FROM data
```

Output:

```
Employee ID #   Presence        Presence Start Time     Presence End Time       GMT Presence Start Time
435             Out Of Office   2020-02-01 00:15:00     2020-02-01 09:00:00     2020-01-31 16:15:00
691             Out Of Office   2020-02-01 04:30:00     2020-02-01 14:30:00     2020-02-01 12:30:00
1927            Out Of Office   2020-02-02 07:00:00     2020-02-02 18:15:00     2020-02-02 15:00:00
5681            Out Of Office   2020-02-02 07:00:00     2020-02-02 15:45:00     2020-02-02 15:00:00
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8efc4/7)

Comment: @SLMSQL I'm glad that works for you; I've added an alternate query using window functions.